# How to make a 3 or 4 column layouts with 960.gs system?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I use 960.gs grid system, the 16 column variant. I want to make a 3 and a 4 column layout. How to to this in detail with 960.gs? The demo on http://960.gs/demo.html only shows samples with 2 columns. Or if there are more, it's not the way I need it.

The columns all should have the same width.

thank you.
daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 columns = groups of 4 from the 16 column layout

3 columns = groups of 4 from the 12 column layout

Comment: if you are using the CSS framework as well (I only use the design temlpates) it should have classes for spanning a number of columns.

Comment: Also, you can get a wider gutter if you use the 12 col for 4 (3*4)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container_16">
    <div class="grid_4">1</div>
    <div class="grid_4">2</div>
    <div class="grid_4">3</div>
    <div class="grid_4">4</div>
</div>
```